# Testing for type in Haskell not working

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

I have a problem where I need to do work based upon the type of Data, but the input may be of the generic "super-type" (not sure if that is correct Haskell lingo).

```
delagator :: Shape -> ShapeMap -> Integer
delagator inShape inDataMap
    | Circle inDataMap = do
        -- do stuff
        0 -- dummy return value
    | Square inDataMap = do
        -- do stuff
        0 -- dummy return value
    | otherwise = do
        -- do stuff
        0 -- dummy return value
```

--- Other information

```
type ShapeMap = H.Map String ShapeData

data Shape = Circle CircleName | Square SquareName | Triangle TriangleName deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

Error: `Not in scope: data constructor 'OpExpr'`

This error is confusing as the data constructor was successfully used in this code before I wrote in this function.

Comment: Can you add the definition of `Shape` and `ShapeMap`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You incorrect pattern match function arguments.
Guards expressions should have Bool type.
I think you mean:

```
delagator :: Shape -> ShapeMap -> Integer
delagator (Circle name) inDataMap = 0
delegator (Square name) inDataMap = 0
delegator _             inDataMap = 0
```

I think you need to read [this page](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses)